# Restore Android Studio Run Button To Normal Behavior

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I was testing something on Android Studio and selected an option in the following menu:

[image: Screenshot]

Now, whenever I click the green run button, it will execute the task I last selected in that menu instead of performing the default task. I have tried restarting Android Studio, but the behavior still remains.

How can I make the run button function as normal?

Answer (score 2):

Click where is written **AnimeFaceKeyboard(dropdown panel)** next to the run button and change it back to your app similar with the image below.

it should fix your issue.

[image]